# Basic search function that searches a sequel database

Tags: php, sqlite, search

I'm a beginner programmer that wants to create a basic search bar that searches my Sequel database. So far I created a search bar in my HTML document: (I'm using Materialize)

```
<nav>
  <div class="nav-wrapper">
    <form method="post">
      <div class="input-field">
        <div class="valign-wrapper">
          <div class="valign" style="width:100%;">
            <input type="text" name="search" placeholder="Search" required>
            <label for="search"><i class="mdi-action-search"></i></label>
            <input type="submit" value="Search"/>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>
  </div>
</nav>
```

I want to have it so this search bar will search my database and then display the information instantly below on the same page. I have searched online and found that one can do this through using PHP. Is there any other way of creating this search bar other than using a PHP document?

If not, I looked under the PHP documentation to try and [download it.](http://php.net/downloads.php) How can I download it using a Mac and Terminal? Then where within a RubyMine project would my PHP document go within (a `public` directory, `views` directory, etc)?

Answer (score 0):

**There are lots of ways other than PHP to do this.** It's really about preference.

Some of your choices are **PHP**(duh), **Ruby**, **Python**, **C#** and **Javascript**.

## Installing PHP is relatively easy on a Mac.

The thing is with running PHP is that it's a Server-Side language, which means that you need a server to process the files before you can view it in your browser.

This may be different from how you are viewing your website right now(I'm guessing you're just opening the files in your browser of choice).

***Have a look at [MAMP](https://www.mamp.info/en/).***

RubyMine is an IDE, which means that it's primary use is just for you to code in. As long as you create a project in the folder where your HTML and PHP reside you will be fine.

Using RubyMine is in now way exclusive to coding and you could use a texteditor if you wanted too.

As for the part about a search feature on your website; I suggest you do some googling on "PHP MySQL search" and choose a tutorial/guide of your choosing.

Comment: How would I do it with Ruby and Javascript?

Comment: This is something that you'd have to learn how to do, there isn't a simple answer I can give you since I don't know what you specifically need.
If you are interested in learning ruby I suggest:
http://railsforzombies.org/